# Active independent variable

Tags: anova, experiment-design, predictor

In a study, there are two independent variables - A and B. We only manipulate variable B. Do we count A as an independent variable in our analysis, even though it has not been manipulated?

Comment: $\text{Var}$ is variance; VaR is value at risk; VAR is vector autoregression. Please be careful with abbreviations and rather spell the word "variable" fully.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide us with a few more details, just so we can understand the context/motivation behind your question?

Comment: A product has two qualities: "functionality" and "aesthetic", which are basically the independent variables. If only aesthetic is manipulated, leaving functionality as it is during a true experiment, do we still say that this study has two independent variables. In fact, the dependent variable, for example, mood, is dependent on the two independent variables. Kindly advise.